# Windows 10 - Change pre logon wallpaper to windows spotlight

Tags: windows-10

In windows 10, the lock screen wallpaper is always new and awesome with windows spotlight. However the pre logon screen which should ideally be same as lock screen isn't windows spotlight. Its same since the day I upgraded to windows 10. Is there a way to fix it? I've `Windows 10 home` edition

Comment: [How to Change the Login Screen Background on Windows 10](http://www.howtogeek.com/223875/how-to-change-the-login-screen-background-on-windows-10/)

Comment: @DavidPostill : The link is to change the login screen background. The question is to change the pre logon screen background.

Comment: In complement of @DavidPostill link: As of today it seems the pre-login and login functions use the same visual element (the login function just blurs it), which can also be a static picture. This is the setting "lock screen background", just type the name in the desktop search bar. Note the "spotlight" element is a dynamically created content, today it is used to promote MS Edge browser by superimposing 3 ugly ads over the picture. This can be prevented by the switching "get fun facts, tips, trick... on your lock screen" off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Unfortunately Microsoft haven't made that entirely possible** , however you could **try** a method which I thought of.

---

## Method:

Well since the location of both images (Login and Lock screen) are visible, **you could get the images from Lock screen to replace one on login.**

1. **Navigate to the Lock screen backgrounds** with this directory:

   ```
   C:Users\{your user name}\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.Windows.ContentDeliveryManager_cw5n1h2txyewy\LocalState\Assets
   ```

   *You may have to enable "Show Hidden Files"* in Control Panel>File Explorer Options
2. **Copy all the images** and make a folder on the desktop. Paste them into there. Rename the images to whatever.jpg
3. Read and follow *[this](http://www.howtogeek.com/112110/how-to-set-a-custom-logon-screen-background-on-windows-7/)* article **until you get to
   Setting your image however take a note if the backgrounds directory**
4. **Take ownership** of the backgrounds directory for login (search it up in Google).
5. **You can then replace them** with the backgrounds from the folder in the desktop

---

*To get them change automatically you can work on a cmd script to randomise each time you log in.*

**Edit:** Also here is a link of where you can get the location of the Lock Screen backgrounds:

http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/5016-lock-screen-background-change-windows-10-a.html

Comment: "You could try" does not make a very good answer. Did you try this yourself? Did it work? If the answer is no then this should be a comment not an answer.

Comment: @DavidPostill No and yes I have not tried this myself however the answer would be too long for a comment. I have changed the background before but not from the Lock screen. So I sort of have

Comment: Then you shouldn't answer at all. Guesses are not answers. If you can find an online reference covering the answer that would be different.

Comment: @DavidPostill OK can I add links to another source that I used

Comment: Hint (as I am feeling generous today): the answer is here [How to Change the Login Screen Background on Windows 10](http://www.howtogeek.com/223875/how-to-change-the-login-screen-background-on-windows-10/)

Comment: A critique on the initial critique comment: comparing to other non-existent answer, this "you could try" answer is good as it come along with workable hypothetical steps. Think it like a pseudo code--those with enough technical skill will be able to apply its intended concept with their own finishing touch. And note that @DavidPostill's link in the comment does not answer the question on how to have spotlight wallpapers as pre logon wallpaper. Bottom line: this topic is not that google-friendly and logical hypothetical answer is better than false answers.