# Change images in Windows 10 pre-login screen

Tags: windows-10, desktop-customization

In Windows 10, ***before*** I select a user and login.

**Before** the one that looks like this:

[image]

There are a number of background images that get cycled every now and again. How do I change which images are used?

This is clearly not linked to my own personalisation settings (single, custom background and no screensaver). Despite being local admin, I can't see anywhere to set "default" or guest user background image. I'm not even sure that it IS a background image (is it? What do I call it?)

Note: I am NOT requesting how to change the background of the login page itself. Also note: The [following question](https://superuser.com/questions/981933/windows-10-change-pre-logon-wallpaper-to-windows-spotlight) is possibly a dupe, but the OP foolishly marked an irrelevant response as "answered" so it's unlikely to attract further input.

Comment: Redstone will fix this problem, uses the same background, upgrade to the preview build or wait till that build is released to the stable branch

Comment: You seem to suggest that this is a (known) bug or feature-gap...? Can you confirm? I've no idea what you mean by "uses the same background"?

Comment: Your talking about the screenshot on the lock screen right?  The current Insider Preview build allows you to set it.  I don't have a link, I don't keep track of stuff I read, I just recall it.  If that isn't what your talking about be more specific.

Comment: Please provide the proper name for the screen you are talking about, if you are not actually talking about the lock screen, then no real reason to mention it.  I just released after reading the question **6** times what screen you actually might be talking about.  Your talking about the screenshot on the lock screen right?  The current Insider Preview build allows you to set it.  I believe my answer still applies, since the Lock and Logon screens will use the same image in RS1 (Redstone 1).

Comment: While I appreciate you taking time to respond, I'm surprised it took 6 attempts to understand "[the screen] before I select a user and login".  As for providing the proper name - you read this bit 6 times too: "I'm not even sure that it IS a background image (is it? What do I call it?)"

Comment: You could have supplied a screenshot of it.  Best way to do that would have been, load a Virtual Machine with Windows 10 installed, and take a screenshot of the virtual machine at the lock screen.

Answer (score 2):

Currently there have been separate background images for the Lock screen and the logon screen itself.  As of Windows 10 (Redstone) Build 14279

> We’re merging the experience so there is just a single background –
>   your Lock screen background. This is similar to the behavior seen on
>   mobile. If you have a custom Lock screen background set, you will see
>   your Lock screen background is now used for both the Lock screen and
>   logon screen. If you’re a Windows Spotlight user – hold tight, you’ll
>   see this change soon in a future build. We’re also working on some
>   additional tweaks here to make the transition between the Lock screen
>   and logging in much smoother.

[Microsoft rolls out Windows 10 Insider Preview build 14279 for PCs, including new features](http://www.neowin.net/news/microsoft-rolls-out-windows-10-insider-preview-build-14279-for-pcs-including-new-features)

Comment: +1 for identifying this as the "Lock Screen". The description however suggests that this applies to the currently-logged-on-user's Lock Screen. My question was about how to change the screen _before_ anyone logs on. I might imply from the link/quote above however that this is possibly a moot point until Redstone 1.

Comment: *I would presume, the screen before the logon screen, is the lock screen.*  [Looks like there are ways to change the lock screen background currently](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/5016-lock-screen-background-change-windows-10-a.html)